# Сократить путь до папки

Tags: javascript, webpack

Есть такой вот код:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Content from "../../../../Core/Scripts/Components/Helpers/Content";
```

Как нибудь можно сократить путь до папки core, что бы использовать это как то так:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Content } from "core";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю можно использовать [resolve-alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias).